# how to limit post content in wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to limit the content of post on wordpress blog home. So after specific amount of words content should be limited and there would be a link saying Read More..
Plz guide me how it can be done in php wordpress theme

Comment: In wordpress, there are a `more` tag. Check the editor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tag in the WordPress editor which you can use to specify the cutoff point on a blog/page excerpt.

You just have to click this button where you want the cutoff to happen

[image]

Then within your template, you just need to add the first parameter to `the_content()` and it will show the content up till that cutoff. If the parameter is not set, it will show all the content.

For example:

```
the_content('Show more...'); // shows content till the cutoff then shows the text supplied

the content(); //shows all the content
```

Read more about the more tag here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More